# i don't have vel_cmd topic in my gztopic list

Tags: gazebo, differential-drive

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

all my dear friends,
hello,

I run the gzserver and gzclient alone and without any parameter and after that i insert a pioneer3at robot with laser scanner in field, i want to drive robot in the field and based on my search i need to vel_cmd topic, but when i enter the gztopic lists, i get this output

```
root@vahid:/home/vahid# gztopic list
/gazebo/default/pose/info
/gazebo/default/gui
/gazebo/default/response
/gazebo/default/world_stats
/gazebo/default/selection
/gazebo/default/model/info
/gazebo/default/light
/gazebo/default/physics/contacts
/gazebo/default/visual
/gazebo/default/request
/gazebo/default/joint
/gazebo/world/modify
/gazebo/default/log/status
/gazebo/default/diagnostics
/gazebo/default/factory
/gazebo/default/model/modify
/gazebo/default/scene
/gazebo/default/physics
/gazebo/default/world_control
/gazebo/server/control
/gazebo/default/sensor
/gazebo/default/pioneer3at/hokuyo/link/laser/scan
```

why vel_cmd topic is not availability in my list ?! i don't want to use ros, just i want to work with standalone version of gazebo, any one can help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2880/i-don%27t-have-vel_cmd-topic-in-my-gztopic-list/) by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 91 on 2013-05-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on 2013-05-24**:
this problem solved for me, as i understand this topic is not exist by default, so we should write a publisher for it like this and change (~/pos_example ) to ( ~/pioneer3at/vel_cmd )and now this topic is exist in my topic list.

**Comment by [VansFannel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4697/vansfannel/) on 2018-10-14**:
How do you control the robot without using ROS? I'm getting crazy figuring out how to publish to topic vel_cmd of this plugin (DiffDrivePlugin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Try using the [DiffDrivePlugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/9e998023acbb0417ca6214047d0a102c9984b927/plugins/DiffDrivePlugin.hh?at=default), of [SkidSteerPlugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/9e998023acbb0417ca6214047d0a102c9984b927/plugins/SkidSteerDrivePlugin.hh?at=default).

Like so:

```
<plugin filename="libDiffDrivePlugin.so" name="diff_drive">
  <left_joint>left_wheel_hinge</left_joint>
  <right_joint>right_wheel_hinge</right_joint>
  <torque>5</torque>
</plugin>
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-05-21**:
Added and issue to add the plugin to the pioneer3at model(https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/issue/9/add-skid-steer-plugin-to-pioneer3at-model)

**Comment by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on 2013-05-22**:
Dear nkoeing, I’ve added the libDiffDrivePlugin.so to my SDF file but i got error because as i understand this plugin is not for pioneer3at robot, so I’ve added the SkidSteerDrivePlugin and i got this [error](https://bitbucket.org/Vahid_Azizi/error-of-skidsteerdriveplugin/src/c36ae63eaaccd7185e279b8c00bb386ac53b20f6/error.txt?at=master), so i commented the MaxForce in SDF file and the error is solved, but I don't have vel_cmd topic until likewise.

**Comment by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on 2013-05-24**:
the error that i mentioned in above comment is for my wrong in SDF file, the MaxForce tag is a child of plugin, i explain correct use in this [link](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/issue/9/add-skid-steer-plugin-to-pioneer3at-model).

**Comment by [VansFannel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4697/vansfannel/) on 2018-10-13**:
How do you control the robot without using ROS? I'm getting crazy figuring out how to publish to topic vel_cmd of this plugin (DiffDrivePlugin).